# Force Numeric Comparison on CharField in djangos orm filter

Tags: python, django

I have a dynamic datastructure in my django Model, basically it's one CharField where text and numbers can be stored:

```
class CSFeature(models.Model):
    csfFeatureValue = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

my Filter:

```
cslist = CSFeature.objects.filter(csfFeatureValue__gte=filter_value)
```

The problem here is, that a string comparison takes place, e.g.

stored value (csfFeatureValue) = 23

- filter_value = 13   filter returns the Model
- filter_value = 3    filter doesn't return the Model (string comparison)

How can i force numeric comparison here? Since this is a generic datamodel i cannot change the datatype of the model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a bad pattern design. We assume that discriminator rule is 'csfFeatureValue' is numeric.

You can override save method to right justify field, instead to store:

```
'13'
```

We will store:

```
'  _total of 198 blank spaces_ 13'
```

Here it is:

```
class CSFeature(models.Model):
    csfFeatureValue = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.csfFeatureValue.isdigit():
            self.csfFeatureValue = "{0:200}".format(int( self.csfFeatureValue ))
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

now you can compare:

```
filter_value = "{0:200}".format( 3 )
cslist = CSFeature.objects.filter(csfFeatureValue__gte=filter_value)
```

I repeat: **recheck your design**. This answer is only a technical approach to solve related issue, but **your problem is not with django query api operation but with model design**.